# update Jquery Jtable plugin depending on a selected row in another Table

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-jtable

hello I have the following snippet of code.
      Departments

```
  <div>Users </div>
  <div id="UserTableContainer"></div>



 <script type="text/javascript">
    var departmentChangeId = 1;


    $(document).ready(function () {


        $('#DepartmentTableContainer').jtable({
            paging: true,
            useBootstrap: true,
            sorting: true,
            selecting: true,
            selectOnRowClick: true,

            title: 'Departments',
            actions: {
                listAction: '/api/Department/GetDepartmentList',
                createAction: '/api/Department/CreateDepartment',
                updateAction: '/api/Department/EditDepartment',
                deleteAction: '/api/Department/DeleteDepartment'
            },
            fields: {
                ID: {
                    key: true,
                    list: false
                },
                TypeId: {
                    title: 'Department Type',
                    options: '/api/Department/GetDepartmentTypeList'
                },
                Label: {
                    title: 'Department'
                },
            },



            //Register to selectionChanged event to hanlde events
            selectionChanged: function () {
                //Get all selected rows
                var $selectedRows = $('#DepartmentTableContainer').jtable('selectedRows');
                departmentChangeId = $selectedRows.data('record').ID;
                //alert(departmentChangeId);
                //

                refresh();
            }
        }).jtable('load');

        $('#UserTableContainer').jtable({
            messages: ArabMessages, //Lozalize
            paging: true,
            useBootstrap: true,
            sorting: true,
            title: 'Employee',
            actions: {
                listAction: '/api/Users/GetEmployee?id=' + departmentChangeId,
                updateAction: '/api/Users/EditEmployee'
            },
            fields: {
                Id: {
                    key: true,
                    list: false
                },
                DepId: {
                    title: ' Department',
                    options: '/api/Department/GetDepartmentTypeList'
                },
                LastName: {
                    title: 'Name'
                },
            }
        });
        $('#UserTableContainer').jtable('load');
    });
```

and these are the two version I use for the refresh function

first

> function refresh() {
>
> ```
>        $('#UserTableContainer').jtable('reload');
>    }
> ```

the second

> function refresh() {
>               $.post("/api/Users/GetEmployee", "id=" + departmentChangeId,
>          function (results) {
>              $('#UserTableContainer').jtable('reload');
>          }
>          , "json");
>
> ```
>     }
> ```

unfortunately both of them dont work 
instead of when I use debugging mode I see that the /api/Users/GetEmployee is visited in both case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try using below code in refresh function

```
$('#UserTableContainer').jtable('load');
```